# How to setup a fully functional "mirror" of a website?

Tags: php, wordpress, shared-hosting, proxy, mirror

PREMISES:

- I have a wordpress website hosted in a shared-hosting
- Since it's a shared hosting, I share the same ip with other GoDaddy customers
- A couple of times, some other customer got malware on their space ..getting OUR ip blacklisted
- I had to contact those guys helping'em to clean their webspace in order to unblock also my websites (on the same ip)
- In general, I'd like to provide a mirror if the main ip isn't reachable
- I can't afford a dedicated ip for this specific project
- I can afford other shared-hosting, and I have accounts with other providers too

Now.. 
**I'd like to provide an additional way to reach one of my website, keeping all the functions.** 
The most important thing is the different IP.

What I need is some sort of proxy running on *mirrorwebsite.com* (hosted on a different hosting provider) that can mirror *originalwebsite.com* keeping all the features (ex. publishing from the wordpress dashboard) and being reachable with a different ip.

This is my specific need. Please help me with that!

Thank you very much in advance,

Comment: Do you want a mirror or a proxy?  A mirror would duplicate all data between two systems.  A proxy would forward requests from one server to your primary server.   A proxy would not work if the primary site IP is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The syncing both ways will be very difficult, and as usual GoDaddy will manage to mess it all up.  I highly recommend you leave them like I did and go for DigitalOcean (I am not a part of them) at digitalocean.com.  It looks all complicated and all but actually isn't, and they will give you a free dedicated ip.

Answer (score 0):

@qsylalyn is right, syncing both ways is nearly impossible in any sort of realtime basis. At that point, you're really talking about a **multi-master MySQL server** configuration between two different servers.

One option is to periodically export your website to an XML file via the **WordPress export plugin** and then import on the second site. Expect some breakage with things like hard-coded image locations, etc, so you'll need a search-and-replace plugin to fix that up. You can run that site in read-only (or treat it as read-only, since without special configuration people could still leave comments on the second site).

Another option is to put CloudFlare in front of your website. (We highly recommend CloudFlare to all of our customers.) This will give you a temporary (but cloudflare-hosted) error page whenever you're down (and also give you tons of other speed and security benefits.)

Unfortunately, this is an area where the design of WordPress (tightly coupled to a MySQL database) makes it pretty hard to have a geographically distant HA/DR backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't afford a dedicated IP but you need another IP? What's the point of getting another shared IP then?
If you want an independent IP you'll have to chip in, and i don't think it's that expensive - quite the contrary. Search around for colocated VPS services with static IPs and root ssh access. If their services don't fulfill all your needs, you can always use that service as a front end and proxy the requests to your other IP (although you're, again, back at square one as far as blocking goes).